# Max size for a SharePoint Services 2.0 MSDE database?

Tags: sharepoint-services, sharepoint

We're (still) running a SharePoint Services 2.0 installation consisting of one site that is using the "built-in" MSDE database for content storage. The current content database DB size is 2.1GB. I thought the max size for a MSDE DB was 2.0GB, but my boss tells me that the version of MSDE that is installed by SPS 2.0 does not have a limit (!)

Does anyone know if there indeed is a hard limit, and if not, what a good practical limit may be? I really cannot find anything on MSDN about this (and it is rather old software.)

Thanks!
Will

Comment: Add'l info: The version of MSDE running on this server appears to be SQL Server 2000 SP4 by the version code in "Add/Remove Programs" - the installation is listed as "Microsoft SQL Server Desktop Engine (SHAREPOINT)" and has version # 8.00.2055

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SPS 2.0 with a default install has a size limit of 2gb **per database**  (which means the MDF and NDF file only).  See [this table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165672%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) for a list of limitations between MSDE and SQl server express 2k5.  I believe tgeh guidance was to uprade to sql server express 2k5 when it shipped slightly after sps 2.0 (mainly for workload performance rather then size, as most users simply added more databases)

Comment: Thanks! Now to convince my boss that this is the case ;)